# how to break lines in textboxes in c# when send to printer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, printing

When I enter some text in the text box I want to break the text into new line (7 characters in 1 line) when printing.

The code is given below

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox24.Text, 
                      new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), 
                      Brushes.Black, 
                      new Point(32, 260));
```

What will I do?

Comment: Insert an `Environment.NewLine` after every 7th character?

Comment: can you explain the codes?

Comment: Which codes? Your codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split at each 7 characters and insert a Environment.NewLine as oerkelens suggested.

```
public string GetPrintReadyString(string originalString)
{
    string result = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < originalString.Length; i += 7)
      result += (originalString.Substring(i, Math.Min(7, originalString.Length - i)) + Environment.NewLine);
    return result;
}
```

Then you can call this method by passing in your string:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(GetPrintReadyString(textBox24.Text), 
                      new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), 
                      Brushes.Black, 
                      new Point(32, 260));
```

Don't forget any exception handling as your string comes from user input.

**EDIT:** If you really really really want it in a single line replace the textBox24.Text with the following:

```
string.Join("", textBox24.Text.Select((c, i) => i > 0 && i % 7 == 0 ? string.Format(Environment.NewLine + c) : c.ToString()))
```

Comment: Why in one line? Don't you need some exception handling?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this;

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(FormatText(textBox24.Text), 
                      new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), 
                      Brushes.Black, 
                      new Point(32, 260));
```

which uses this method. it loops throught the entered string inserting a new line after every 7th character

```
public string FormatText(string input)
{
    string returnText = "";
    int charCounter = 0;
    foreach(char c in input)
    {
        result += c;
        i++;
        if(i == 7)
        {
            result += Environment.NewLine;
            charCounter=0;
        }
    }
    return returnText;
}
```